# Add all files from folder except one but include it after, in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

This is a reduced scenario: FolderA with several files and FolderB with several files.

I am trying to enqueue files in the following order: all files from FolderA in the first place except a certain one, then files from FolderB, and finally that file from FolderA.

```
gulp.src( [
    paths.folderA + '*.js',
    paths.folderB + '*.js',
    paths.folderA + 'this_file_should_go_last.js',
] )
.pipe( $.concat( 'etc.js' ) )
// ...
```

However, this doesn't work as I expect. Is it possible to achieve this without specifying each individual file?

Answer (score 0):

Using [merge2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge2) I figured out this can be solved by setting a stream to use the first set (without the file) and the second stream with the file.

```
merge2( gulp.src( [
        paths.folderA + '!(this_file_should_go_last).js',
        paths.folderB + '*.js'
    ] ),
    gulp.src( [
        paths.folderA + 'this_file_should_go_last.js'
    ] )
)
.pipe( $.concat( 'etc.js' ) )
// ...
```